# callback or listener between Flutter Dart Class

Tags: dart, flutter

I am a newby and just started coding in Dart/Flutter for a mobile application. I am trying to create an interface or callback or listener between to class but I can't figure out the best way. Right, the application is simple, it starts, show a splashscreen and after a timer expired, I have to show a another screen. I am using the `SplashScreen` lib to do it but I would like to call a listener/callback to start the other screen. Below is my code for a better understanding of the structure.

`main.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'splash_screen.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MyHomeSplashScreen().myHomeSplashScreen();
  }
}
}
```

`splash_screen.dart`

```
class MyHomeSplashScreen{
  SplashScreen myHomeSplashScreen(){
    return SplashScreen(
        seconds: 5,
        navigateAfterSeconds: null,//I want my callback there,
        title: _mySplashText(),
        imageBackground: new AssetImage("assets/images/splash_screen.png"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        styleTextUnderTheLoader: new TextStyle(),
        photoSize: 100.0,
        //onClick: ()=>print("Flutter Egypt"),
        loaderColor: Colors.white,
      );
  }

  Text _mySplashText(){
    return Text('MyHome', 
      style: new TextStyle(
        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize: 80.0,
        color: Colors.white
      ));
  }
}
```

The callback/listener should be called in the `splash_screen.dart` as shown in my example and have the associated code in the `main.dart`

Any idea how to do it at best ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try  extends **ValueNotifier**
and usd **addListener** to callBack